# windows cmd or powershell to search string in a file?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

in a txt file I have this line:

`<em:version>0.0.0.2</em:version>`

Which cmd (dos or powershell) can I use fetch this?

`0.0.0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PS> '<em:version>0.0.0.2</em:version>' -replace '<[^>]+>'
0.0.0.2

# replace file content
(Get-Content file.txt) -replace '<[^>]+>'
```

Comment: works. But how can I spcify the file itself now i'm runnning the cmd at a folder's level

Comment: I edited the thread, give it a try

Comment: That will only work if there is a single line of text in the file!

Comment: Works for me just fine with a multi line text file.

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell can parse XML directly. No need for regular expressions. Here's an example with a FireFox install.rdf file. (I'm guessing your file might be something like that.)

```
PS> [xml]$rdf = Get-Content .\install.rdf
PS> $rdf.RDF.Description.version
1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$fileContent=gc "path to text file"

$pattern =  '(?i)<em:version[^>]*>(.*)</em:version>'


$result = [Regex]::Matches($fileContent, $pattern)

$result | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Groups[1].Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  A one line DOS command:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=<>" %%A in (`type "File.txt" ^| find "<em:version>"`) do echo.%%A
```